# I want to return the points from my TicTacToe class to my main class but it keeps giving me this error?

Tags: java

```
12 errors and 12 warnings found:
--------------
*** Errors ***
--------------
File: C:\Users\John\Documents\Computer Science\Summative\TicTacToe.java  [line: 38]
Error: Syntax error on token "int", @ expected
File: C:\Users\John\Documents\Computer Science\Summative\TicTacToe.java  [line: 38]
Error: Syntax error, insert "enum Identifier" to complete EnumHeaderName
File: C:\Users\John\Documents\Computer Science\Summative\TicTacToe.java  [line: 38]
Error: Syntax error, insert "EnumBody" to complete BlockStatement
File: C:\Users\John\Documents\Computer Science\Summative\TicTacToe.java  [line: 40]
Error: Syntax error on token ",", . expected
File: C:\Users\John\Documents\Computer Science\Summative\TicTacToe.java  [line: 42]
Error: Syntax error on token "int", @ expected
File: C:\Users\John\Documents\Computer Science\Summative\TicTacToe.java  [line: 42]
Error: Syntax error, insert "enum Identifier" to complete EnumHeaderName
File: C:\Users\John\Documents\Computer Science\Summative\TicTacToe.java  [line: 42]
Error: Syntax error, insert "EnumBody" to complete BlockStatement
File: C:\Users\John\Documents\Computer Science\Summative\TicTacToe.java  [line: 44]
Error: Syntax error on token ",", . expected
File: C:\Users\John\Documents\Computer Science\Summative\TicTacToe.java  [line: 47]
Error: Syntax error on token "int", @ expected
File: C:\Users\John\Documents\Computer Science\Summative\TicTacToe.java  [line: 47]
Error: Syntax error, insert "enum Identifier" to complete EnumHeaderName
File: C:\Users\John\Documents\Computer Science\Summative\TicTacToe.java  [line: 47]
Error: Syntax error, insert "EnumBody" to complete BlockStatement
File: C:\Users\John\Documents\Computer Science\Summative\TicTacToe.java  [line: 49]
Error: Syntax error on token ",", . expected
```

and here is my code

```
  public class TicTacToe
  {
    public int winPoints1;
    public int winPoints2;
    public int losePoints1;
    public int losePoints2;
    public int tiePoints1;
    public int tiePoints2;

    public TicTacToe (int player1, int player2)
    {     
    int winCombo[][] = new int[][] 
    {
        {1, 2, 3}, {1, 4, 7}, {1, 5, 9},
        {4, 5, 6}, {2, 5, 8}, {3, 5, 7},
        {7, 8, 9}, {3, 6, 9}
    }; 
    for (int i = 0; i > 8;i++)
    {     
        if (player2 == winCombo[i][0])
        {
            winPoints2++;
            losePoints1++;

        }
        else
            tiePoints2++;

        if (player1 == winCombo[i][0])
        {
            winPoints1++;
            losePoints2++;

        }
        else 
            tiePoints1++;
    }
    public int getWinPoints()
    {
        return winPoints1, winPoints2;
    }     
        public int getLosePoints()
        {
            return losePoints1, losePoints2;

        }
        public int getTiePoints()
        {
            return tiePoints1, tiePoints2;

        }

      }          
    }
```

Comment: you cannot return two int from a single method. you can return array instead

Comment: Note that you need an extra `}` before `public int getWinPoints` and need to drop an extra `}` in the end of file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java does not implement returning multiple values from a single function.

If you want to return multiple values, your choices are

1) pass in parameters that the function will modify, and use the modified parameters in the outer function (note that ints and all primitives are passed by value, and won't work)

2) return an object containing all of the values you want to return (for example, an array or ArrayList of ints)

Comment: Sorry can you give me an example i didn't get it.

Comment: @user2343211 Try `return new int[] {losePoints1, losePoints2};` and making the function `public int[]` instead of `public int`. Then of the returned `int[]` `[0]` is `losePoints1` while `[1]` is `losePoints2`.

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious thing in that code is that Java doesn't support multiple returns, so you can't `return tiePoints1, tiePoints2;`. You can only return one value.